# Ouibounce Exit Pop-up - Fire 2 times with different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I use Ouibounce on my site for exit lightbox pop-ups but would like to be able to have it fire just 2 times while on a specific page, where the first time it displays one type of content, and then the second time it displays another.

I can either get it to pop 1 time or infinite times but I'm struggling with getting it to fire a specific number of times, with control on what content appears.

Any help would be appreciated.